# Eclipse-Marketplace Error Message in Linux machine

Tags: eclipse-marketplace

Eclipse Indigo :

once i go into eclipse market place option i got this message :
Unexpected exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

this is in mu linux machine can i know why am i getting this message.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue happen to me... I couldn't get the Indigo Marketplace Client to install, so I had to switch to the Helios repository and install that one. It installed, but running it gave me the same error message you got. I had to switch back to Indigo and install (upgrade) to that one, and then everything worked.

Click Help->Install New Software->Add, and add the location:
http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem with window 7 64 bit. I fixed it by changing the Proxy of windows which eclipse uses by through control panel.